# Are all shared libraries contained in packages whose name begin with "lib"?

Tags: packaging

So do soname bumps happen in packages whose name start by "lib" only?

[Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#run-time-shared-libraries) tells about run-time shared libraries:

> Normally, the run-time shared library and its SONAME symlink should be
> placed in a package named librarynamesoversion, where soversion is the
> version number in the SONAME of the shared library. Alternatively, if
> it would be confusing to directly append soversion to libraryname (if,
> for example, libraryname itself ends in a number), you should use
> libraryname-soversion instead.

But do all library names start by "lib"?

Comment: It's up the packager as to which standard they follow *generally*.  Ubuntu follow Debian package rules, and thus packages in Ubuntu repositories will be more uniform, but even Qt & GTK can have differences. When you get to 3rd party packages however, they can follow whatever rules they prefer, so relying on a package that contains libraries to start with "*lib*" seems very risky for me, unless you clarify what specific package, from what source you're after as currently you've provided no parameters (*you'll note some package differences in those from BSD upstream for example!*)

Answer (score 3):

Please see this [Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561273/is-liblibrary-name-a-so-a-naming-convention-for-static-libraries-in-linux) for more information.

Generally, it is a *convention* in Unix-like systems that shared libraries being with `lib` (the GCC linker looks for these files by default).

But this is only for the files themselves. Such shared files can either be included in another package (which may be named however the author likes), or in a dedicated package, which is most likely also named after the convention (starting with `lib`).

Generally, since this is not a strict rule, you'll most likely find examples of the convention being broken. But in most cases, dedicated packages with shared libraries will begin with `lib`, following the naming convention.

As for soname bumps, this will only happen when backward-incompatible changes are made. For instance, with Ubuntu 22.04, OpenSSL was bumped to v. 3.0.2, and the soname of `libssl` was bumped to `libssl.so.3`.

But for official libraries this will not happen during the release of an Ubuntu version, but rather from one version to another. However, there is no way to tell if some 3rd party developer decides to release a new major version of a library, which results in a soname bump.

Comment: I suppose using a PPA can introduce a soname bumped version of a shared library. Do you happen to know, if there is such a PPA for 20.04?

Comment: Can you name such a rule-breaking Ubuntu package that contain a run-time shared library?

Comment: Could e.g. some python packages such as python3-urllib3 have different name in a PPA?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know. 